# Testing Quagga onProcessed, onDetected in angular 4 Jasmine and karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, quaggajs

Since i am learning testing of angular 4 apps. I started writing test cases in jasmin and karma for my angular 4 App having barcode scanner.I Used Quagga for barcode scanning. can anyone tell me how to stub Quagga.onProcessed and Quagga.onDetected ?? thanks in advance

```
     Quagga.onProcessed(result => {
// want to return result

     });


     Quagga.onDetected(result => {
      // console result

     });
```